# Change the color of border for DatePicker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, datepicker

I am using DatePicker using the following code

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:theme="@style/DatePicker"
    />
```

style DatePicker:

```
<style name="DatePicker" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
```

I am getting the DatePicker as [image]

Now I want to change the color of the border around the date, month and year...

[image]

Can anyone guide me on this....

Comment: 1.  you can try changing the accent color in colors.xml or 
2. you can to create a custom date picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SlideDateTimePicker](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker). and apply theme accordingly:

```
new SlideDateTimePicker.Builder(getFragmentManager())
    .setListener(listener)
    .setInitialDate(dateDOB)
    .setTheme(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent))
    .setIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent))
    .setMaxDate(SupportFunctions.getPreviousDate(18))
    .build()
   .show();
```

[image]

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: I am using DatePicker and I have to stick to it.... Is there any way to change the Datepicker itself